# EF Core, Fluent API and relations: problem with incorrect SQL generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using a standard asp.net core 2 identity and entity framework core.

How's the User, Role and UserRole relation are configured:

```cs
public sealed class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Role : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API configuration:

```cs
    protected override void ConfigureRelations(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRole> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(q => q.User)
               .WithOne(q => q.UserRole)
               .HasForeignKey<UserRole>(q => q.UserId);

        builder.HasOne(q => q.Role)
               .WithMany(q => q.UserRoles)
               .HasForeignKey(q => q.RoleId);
    }
```

When I'm trying to get the list of Users with their UserRoles:

```cs
context.Users.Include(q => q.UserRole).ToList();
```

I'm getting the runtime exception of incorrect t-sql generated:

```
Invalid column name 'UserId1'.
Invalid column name 'RoleId1'.
Invalid column name 'UserId1'.
```

and the T-SQL:

```sql
SELECT
[a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp],
[a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd],
[a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash],
[a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp],
[a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName],
[u.UserRole].[UserId],
[u.UserRole].[RoleId],
[u.UserRole].[RoleId1],
[u.UserRole].[UserId1]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
      LEFT JOIN [AspNetUserRoles] AS [u.UserRole] ON [a].[Id] = [u.UserRole].[UserId1]
```

as you can see, for some reason, the ef core used non-existent fields "UserId1" and "RoleId1" instead of "UserId" and "RoleId".

Any ideas why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reconfigure the Identity Context which already works correctly.  Is this not the case?

Comment: All I have done is to set the PK type to Guid instead of string and added four navigation properties: User.UserRole , Role.List<UserRole> , UserRole.User and UserRole.Role.
Without adding them manually it is not possible to include any relational data, because you don't have anything to write in .Include() method.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't configure relations twice somewhere? Check generated migration skript, does type change generated it correctly?

Comment: Also you've incorrectly setup your Relationships.  You'll need [a Many to Many](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration) relationship. Users can have many roles, and roles can belong to many users.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, you're right! Once I've changed the User.UserRole to User.List<UserRole> - everything started to work!